# How can I convert stl files to ply files efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, file-conversion

Is there a way of converting stl (STereoLithography) files to ply (Polygon File Format) format in Python? I have to use another program that only accepts ply format.
Here is the link to the program that I want to use: http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/ShapeSPH/ShapeDescriptor/
Any other suggestions regarding how I could use this program?

My second question, can I use this .exe file by using Python? Should it be something like :

```
os.popen("file.exe --in value", shell=True)
os.system("file.exe --in value")
```

Am I right?

Comment: by STL file you mean C++ STL source code ? If not you should remove the C++ and STL tags

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Comment: For the second part of your question (which really should be a separate question), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/3775798 .